# JTextPane only shows inserted components in single line

Tags: java, jtextpane

I need to insert numbers of `JButtons` in a `JTextPane`. It is done via `insertComponent()` method. but there is a problem, the components are in a line and `JScrollPane` doesn't scroll neither vertically nor horizontally (however I just want vertically). what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to add spaces between the buttons, these allow the `JTextPane` to wrap the buttons.

Alternatively, you can insert a single `JComponent` and add the buttons as children of that single component. This would allow you to use any layout you like for the buttons (`FlowLayout` is probably what you want).

Comment: +1 for the spaces suggestion. The FlowLayout idea would re-flow with the text ass a very big button, which is probably not what Soheil wants